# Multiple-cursors in Emacs does not modify all the cursors

Tags: emacs, multiple-cursor

I have installed the multiple-cursors package but, I cannot manage to work properly. Only one cursor can be modified, the rest of the cursors do nothing.

I have configured my .emacs file for the multi-cursors package as is shown below:

```
(require 'multiple-cursors)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m c") 'mc/edit-lines)
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-<") 'mc/mark-all-like-this)
```

Can anybody help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess some other package is interfering. Try commenting out everything in your config file except for the lines quoted above, and see if multiple-cursors works. If so, uncomment one bit after the other until you find the one that causes the problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51834/19819

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that once upon a time the original poster was presented with an interactive question asking him/her whether to perform the same command for all cursors; and, the O.P. answered the question with a "no".  Whereupon the Multiple Cursors package added an entry to the `mc/lists-file`, which has a default location of:  `(locate-user-emacs-file ".mc-lists.el")` -- see https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/master/multiple-cursors-core.el#L652

The O.P. should open up the above-mentioned file and see if his/her prior choice should be manually removed.  The file contains something like this:

```
;; This file is automatically generated by the multiple-cursors extension.
;; It keeps track of your preferences for running commands with multiple cursors.

(setq mc/cmds-to-run-for-all
      '(
      my-custom-function-one
      org-self-insert-command
      ))

(setq mc/cmds-to-run-once
      '(
      mime-preview-scroll-down-entity
      my-custom-function-two
      ))


(provide '.multiple_cursors)
```